# Unable to access SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Framework in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, nuget

We're calling a PowerShell script on a remote server which returns an enumeration value `[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.CompletionResult]`. When we run the script on the local machine, the PowerShell script does not know what this enumeration is and fails.

I have gathered the SqlServer PowerShell Extension NuGet package and its dependencies and attempted to installed it.

*Note, this is for an offline installation.*

Install packages:

```
Placed the SqlServer nupkg file into  C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache\sql_server\powershell_module

C:\OT\nugets>"C:\Program Files\NuGet\nuget.exe" install "SqlServer" -Source "C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache\sql_server\powershell_module" -OutputDirectory "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" -Version "21.1.18245
Feeds used:
  C:\Users\administrator\.nuget\packages\
  C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache\sql_server\powershell_module
```

I'm running with PowerShell and .NET versions:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.693
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.693
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

C:\DotNetVersions>DotNetVersions.exe /b
4.0.0.0
4.6.01586
```

I can see that the SqlServer module is being picked up fine.

```
PS C:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable


    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0.1      Microsoft.PowerShell.Operation.V... {Get-OperationValidation, Invoke-OperationValidation}
Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-PackageSource...}
Script     3.4.0      Pester                              {Describe, Context, It, Should...}
Script     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet                       {Install-Module, Find-Module, Save-Module, Update-Module...}
Script     1.2        PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler, Remove-PSReadlineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadlineOption...}
Script     21.1.18245 SqlServer                           {Add-RoleMember, Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase, Add-SqlAvailabilityGroupListenerStaticIp, Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext...}


    Directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.0.0.0    AppBackgroundTask                   {Disable-AppBackgroundTaskDiagnosticLog, Enable-AppBackgroundTaskDiagnosticLog, Set-AppBackgroundTaskResourcePolicy, Unregister-AppBackgroundTask...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    AppLocker                           {Get-AppLockerFileInformation, Get-AppLockerPolicy, New-AppLockerPolicy, Set-AppLockerPolicy...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    AppvClient                          {Add-AppvClientConnectionGroup, Add-AppvClientPackage, Add-AppvPublishingServer, Disable-Appv...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    Appx                                {Add-AppxPackage, Get-AppxPackage, Get-AppxPackageManifest, Remove-AppxPackage...}
Script     1.0.0.0    AssignedAccess                      {Clear-AssignedAccess, Get-AssignedAccess, Set-AssignedAccess}
Manifest   1.0        BestPractices                       {Get-BpaModel, Get-BpaResult, Invoke-BpaModel, Set-BpaResult}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    BitsTransfer                        {Add-BitsFile, Complete-BitsTransfer, Get-BitsTransfer, Remove-BitsTransfer...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    BranchCache                         {Add-BCDataCacheExtension, Clear-BCCache, Disable-BC, Disable-BCDowngrading...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    CimCmdlets                          {Get-CimAssociatedInstance, Get-CimClass, Get-CimInstance, Get-CimSession...}
Manifest   1.0        ConfigCI                            {Get-SystemDriver, New-CIPolicyRule, New-CIPolicy, Get-CIPolicy...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    DirectAccessClientComponents        {Disable-DAManualEntryPointSelection, Enable-DAManualEntryPointSelection, Get-DAClientExperienceConfiguration, Get-DAEntryPointTableItem...}
Script     3.0        Dism                                {Add-AppxProvisionedPackage, Add-WindowsDriver, Add-WindowsCapability, Add-WindowsImage...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    DnsClient                           {Resolve-DnsName, Clear-DnsClientCache, Get-DnsClient, Get-DnsClientCache...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    EventTracingManagement              {New-EtwTraceSession, Get-EtwTraceSession, Set-EtwTraceSession, Send-EtwTraceSession...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    International                       {Get-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride, Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride, Get-WinHomeLocation, Set-WinHomeLocation...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    iSCSI                               {Get-IscsiTargetPortal, New-IscsiTargetPortal, Remove-IscsiTargetPortal, Update-IscsiTargetPortal...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    IscsiTarget                         {Add-ClusteriSCSITargetServerRole, Add-IscsiVirtualDiskTargetMapping, Checkpoint-IscsiVirtualDisk, Convert-IscsiVirtualDisk...}
Script     1.0.0.0    ISE                                 {New-IseSnippet, Import-IseSnippet, Get-IseSnippet}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    Kds                                 {Add-KdsRootKey, Get-KdsRootKey, Test-KdsRootKey, Set-KdsConfiguration...}
Manifest   1.0.1.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive        {Compress-Archive, Expand-Archive}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics    {Get-WinEvent, Get-Counter, Import-Counter, Export-Counter...}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Host           {Start-Transcript, Stop-Transcript}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts  {Add-LocalGroupMember, Disable-LocalUser, Enable-LocalUser, Get-LocalGroup...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-ItemProperty, Join-Path...}
Script     1.0        Microsoft.PowerShell.ODataUtils     Export-ODataEndpointProxy
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {Get-Acl, Set-Acl, Get-PfxCertificate, Get-Credential...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-Table, Format-Wide...}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Disable-WSManCredSSP, Enable-WSManCredSSP, Get-WSManCredSSP, Set-WSManQuickConfig...}
Manifest   1.0        MMAgent                             {Disable-MMAgent, Enable-MMAgent, Set-MMAgent, Get-MMAgent...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    MsDtc                               {New-DtcDiagnosticTransaction, Complete-DtcDiagnosticTransaction, Join-DtcDiagnosticResourceManager, Receive-DtcDiagnosticTransaction...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    NetAdapter                          {Disable-NetAdapter, Disable-NetAdapterBinding, Disable-NetAdapterChecksumOffload, Disable-NetAdapterEncapsulatedPacketTaskOffload...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetConnection                       {Get-NetConnectionProfile, Set-NetConnectionProfile}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetEventPacketCapture               {New-NetEventSession, Remove-NetEventSession, Get-NetEventSession, Set-NetEventSession...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    NetLbfo                             {Add-NetLbfoTeamMember, Add-NetLbfoTeamNic, Get-NetLbfoTeam, Get-NetLbfoTeamMember...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetNat                              {Get-NetNat, Get-NetNatExternalAddress, Get-NetNatStaticMapping, Get-NetNatSession...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    NetQos                              {Get-NetQosPolicy, Set-NetQosPolicy, Remove-NetQosPolicy, New-NetQosPolicy}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    NetSecurity                         {Get-DAPolicyChange, New-NetIPsecAuthProposal, New-NetIPsecMainModeCryptoProposal, New-NetIPsecQuickModeCryptoProposal...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetSwitchTeam                       {New-NetSwitchTeam, Remove-NetSwitchTeam, Get-NetSwitchTeam, Rename-NetSwitchTeam...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetTCPIP                            {Get-NetIPAddress, Get-NetIPInterface, Get-NetIPv4Protocol, Get-NetIPv6Protocol...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetworkConnectivityStatus           {Get-DAConnectionStatus, Get-NCSIPolicyConfiguration, Reset-NCSIPolicyConfiguration, Set-NCSIPolicyConfiguration}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetworkSwitchManager                {Disable-NetworkSwitchEthernetPort, Enable-NetworkSwitchEthernetPort, Get-NetworkSwitchEthernetPort, Remove-NetworkSwitchEthernetPortIPAddress...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetworkTransition                   {Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding, Disable-NetDnsTransitionConfiguration, Disable-NetIPHttpsProfile, Disable-NetNatTransitionConfiguration...}
Manifest   1.0        NFS                                 {Get-NfsMappedIdentity, Get-NfsNetgroup, Install-NfsMappingStore, New-NfsMappedIdentity...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    PcsvDevice                          {Get-PcsvDevice, Start-PcsvDevice, Stop-PcsvDevice, Restart-PcsvDevice...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    PKI                                 {Add-CertificateEnrollmentPolicyServer, Export-Certificate, Export-PfxCertificate, Get-CertificateAutoEnrollmentPolicy...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    PlatformIdentifier                  Get-PlatformIdentifier
Manifest   1.0.0.0    PnpDevice                           {Get-PnpDevice, Get-PnpDeviceProperty, Enable-PnpDevice, Disable-PnpDevice}
Manifest   1.1        PrintManagement                     {Add-Printer, Add-PrinterDriver, Add-PrinterPort, Get-PrintConfiguration...}
Manifest   1.1        PSDesiredStateConfiguration         {Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager, Start-DscConfiguration, Test-DscConfiguration, Publish-DscConfiguration...}
Script     1.0.0.0    PSDiagnostics                       {Disable-PSTrace, Disable-PSWSManCombinedTrace, Disable-WSManTrace, Enable-PSTrace...}
Binary     1.1.0.0    PSScheduledJob                      {New-JobTrigger, Add-JobTrigger, Remove-JobTrigger, Get-JobTrigger...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    PSWorkflow                          {New-PSWorkflowExecutionOption, New-PSWorkflowSession, nwsn}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    PSWorkflowUtility                   Invoke-AsWorkflow
Manifest   2.0.0.0    RemoteDesktop                       {Get-RDCertificate, Set-RDCertificate, New-RDCertificate, New-RDVirtualDesktopDeployment...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    ScheduledTasks                      {Get-ScheduledTask, Set-ScheduledTask, Register-ScheduledTask, Unregister-ScheduledTask...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    SecureBoot                          {Confirm-SecureBootUEFI, Set-SecureBootUEFI, Get-SecureBootUEFI, Format-SecureBootUEFI...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    SecurityCmdlets                     {Backup-SecurityPolicy, Restore-SecurityPolicy, Backup-AuditPolicy, Restore-AuditPolicy}
Script     1.0.0.0    ServerCore                          {Get-DisplayResolution, Set-DisplayResolution}
Script     2.0.0.0    ServerManager                       {Get-WindowsFeature, Install-WindowsFeature, Uninstall-WindowsFeature, Enable-ServerManagerStandardUserRemoting...}
Cim        1.0.0.0    ServerManagerTasks                  {Get-SMCounterSample, Get-SMPerformanceCollector, Start-SMPerformanceCollector, Stop-SMPerformanceCollector...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    SmbShare                            {Get-SmbShare, Remove-SmbShare, Set-SmbShare, Block-SmbShareAccess...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    SmbWitness                          {Get-SmbWitnessClient, Move-SmbWitnessClient, gsmbw, msmbw...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    SoftwareInventoryLogging            {Get-SilComputer, Get-SilComputerIdentity, Get-SilSoftware, Get-SilWindowsUpdate...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    StartLayout                         {Export-StartLayout, Import-StartLayout, Get-StartApps}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    Storage                             {Add-InitiatorIdToMaskingSet, Add-PartitionAccessPath, Add-PhysicalDisk, Add-TargetPortToMaskingSet...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    TLS                                 {New-TlsSessionTicketKey, Enable-TlsSessionTicketKey, Disable-TlsSessionTicketKey, Export-TlsSessionTicketKey...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    TroubleshootingPack                 {Get-TroubleshootingPack, Invoke-TroubleshootingPack}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    TrustedPlatformModule               {Get-Tpm, Initialize-Tpm, Clear-Tpm, Unblock-Tpm...}
Binary     2.1.639.0  UEV                                 {Clear-UevConfiguration, Clear-UevAppxPackage, Restore-UevBackup, Set-UevTemplateProfile...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    UserAccessLogging                   {Enable-Ual, Disable-Ual, Get-Ual, Get-UalDns...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    VpnClient                           {Add-VpnConnection, Set-VpnConnection, Remove-VpnConnection, Get-VpnConnection...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    Wdac                                {Get-OdbcDriver, Set-OdbcDriver, Get-OdbcDsn, Add-OdbcDsn...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    Whea                                {Get-WheaMemoryPolicy, Set-WheaMemoryPolicy}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    WindowsDeveloperLicense             {Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense, Unregister-WindowsDeveloperLicense, Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration}
Script     1.0        WindowsErrorReporting               {Enable-WindowsErrorReporting, Disable-WindowsErrorReporting, Get-WindowsErrorReporting}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    WindowsSearch                       {Get-WindowsSearchSetting, Set-WindowsSearchSetting}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    WindowsUpdate                       Get-WindowsUpdateLog
```

To prove they are not available I can see that the object is not available in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.CompletionResult]::Succeeded
Unable to find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.CompletionResult].
At line:1 char:1
+ [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.CompletionResult]::Succeede ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.SqlSe...ompletionResult:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

When running the script that executes the PowerShell on the remote server, the same issue is seen, it's not available:

```
C:\Overnight>backup.cmd
Unable to find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.CompletionResult].
At C:\OT\Overnight\backup.ps1:24 char:11
+ $status = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.CompletionResult] ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.SqlSe...ompletionResult:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Why is the `[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.CompletionResult]` enumeration not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got there and realised that I needed to simply import the library in my script. I had assumed this would work without as on the remote server there is no import.

```
PS C:\> Import-module -name SqlServer
PS C:\> [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.CompletionResult]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     CompletionResult                         System.Enum
```